# What is unary + used for in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have found some code from [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)

```
  _.map = _.collect = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    var results = [];
    if (obj == null) return results;
    if (nativeMap && obj.map === nativeMap) return obj.map(iterator, context);
    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      results[results.length] = iterator.call(context, value, index, list);
    });
    if (obj.length === +obj.length) results.length = obj.length;
    return results;
  };
```

I would like to know what `if (obj.length === +obj.length)` does?

Comment: Although I understand very well what `a === +a` does, I'd rather the author be explicit in the intentions and use `typeof a === 'number'`, or `Object.prototype.toString.call(a) === '[object Number]'`.

Comment: @amnotiam, it should probably use an `isFinite` check as `NaN` and `Infinity` are important edge-cases to avoid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`+length` is a method to convert anything to a number.

If it's a number, the value doesn't change, and the comparison returns true.
If it's not a number, the assertion is false.

Comment: When you say *"method"* I'm sure you don't mean function/method, but it could be confusing to someone. ;)

Comment: @amnotiam `method` in the meaning of `way`. @Cybrix In case you're wondering for the purpose of `if (l == +l) r.l = o.l;` in the code: If the passed object is an array(-like) object, the `results` list also gets the length of the `obj` object. Relevant code is also visible at the `_.each` -> `Array.prototype.forEach` method (function ;)).

Answer (score 6):

That's the unary + operator. This website has a great article on its uses with the different data types in javascript.

http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/unary-add/

I'll steal the introduction, but it is really worth reading if you are into javascript.

> In JavaScript it is possible to use the + operator alone before a
>   single element. This indicates a math operation and tries to convert
>   the element to a number. If the conversion fails, it will evaluate to
>   NaN. This is especially useful when one wants to convert a string to a
>   number quickly, but can also be used on a select set of other types.
>
> The unary + operator, when used on types other than string, will
>   internally attempt to call valueOf() or toString() (in that order) and
>   then attempt to convert the result to a number. Thusly, the unary +
>   operator can successfully convert many of the native JS types with
>   certain restrictions:

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"*.

Answer (score 2):

This is test, if `obj.length` is number.

Doing arithmetic operation on string converts it to integer (and + is unary operation.. which doesn't do anything :-) ), and === operator does type-wise comparsion

`a === b <=> (a == b) && (typeof a) == (typeof b)`

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to try this

console.log(typeof +"3") = number

console.log(typeof "3") = string

This makes everything clear.