# Why "typeof + ''" returns 'number'?

Tags: javascript

Let's try to type code below in console:

```
typeof + ''
```

This returns 'number', while typeof itself without argument throws an error. Why?

Comment: Because of the unary plus.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081880/what-is-unary-used-for-in-javascript

Comment: The reason why `+` is not interpreted as addition or concatenation operator is because `typeof` itself is a unary operator, not a function: http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.3. Treating `+` as unary plus is the only way to make this expression valid.

Answer (score 7):

The [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Negation.29) invokes the internal `ToNumber` algorithm on the string. `+'' === 0`

```
typeof + ''
// The `typeof` operator has the same operator precedence than the unary plus operator,
// but these are evaluated from right to left so your expression is interpreted as:
typeof (+ '')
// which evaluates to:
typeof 0
"number"
```

Differently from `parseInt`, the internal `ToNumber` algorithm invoked by the `+` operator evaluates empty strings (as well as white-space only strings) to Number `0`. Scrolling down a bit from the [`ToNumber` spec](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1):

> A *StringNumericLiteral* that is empty or contains only white space is converted to `+0`.

Here's a quick check on the console:

```
>>> +''
<<< 0
>>> +' '
<<< 0
>>> +'\t\r\n'
<<< 0
//parseInt with any of the strings above will return NaN
```

#### *For reference:*

- [Whats the significant use of Unary Plus and Minus operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5450076/1331430) (SO)
- [ES5 #9.3.1 ToNumber Applied to the String Type](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1) (ES5 Spec)
- [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) (MDN)

Answer (score 1):

That evaluates to `typeof(+'')`, not `(typeof) + ('')`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript interprets the following `+ ''` as `0` so :

`typeof + ''` will echo `number'

To answer your second question, `typeof` takes an argument so if you call it by itself it will throw an error same thing if you call `if` by itself.