# What does a + prefix do in this context?

Tags: javascript

Here is a line of  code from [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).  What is that plus prefix for in this line?

```
if (obj.length === +obj.length) { // plus prefix?
```

Comment: Converts to a number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is unary + used for in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081880/what-is-unary-used-for-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't know where you found that code, but the `breaker` thing will never work.  It looks like it's intended that the iterator function can return an empty object to indicate that it's time to return, but it will inevitably return a *different* empty object than that one because "breaker" is local to that function.

Comment: @pure_code no, the `+` prefix **converts** to a number, so that test makes sure that "obj" is an array-like object and that its "length" property is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This forces the value of `obj.length` to be a `Number`.  Essentially this is done to make sure that the default `length` value for an array-like object has not been overridden so that it can be iterated properly.

`breaker` will do nothing in this context because even another empty object `{}` will evaluate to `false` when compared to `breaker` .. even without an equivalence comparison.

However, `breaker` is not used in that context because it is defined *outside* of the `.each` function, which appears different than what you are showing here.  Instead, it is used to force a "break" from other looping methods:

```
_.every = _.all = function(obj, iterator, context) {
  /* snip */
  if (!(result = result && iterator.call(context, value, index, list)))
      return breaker;
```

You can see that if the result is not truthy in "every," we want to break immediately.  `_.every` calls `_.each`, and it will return `breaker` which will be true when compared to itself, allowing for an immediate break.

Comment: @pure_code if you define `breaker` inside of `.each`, then it will always be a new object on every call to `.each`.  We don't want that -- what we want is for `breaker` to be the same throughout all of `_`

Comment: @pure_code don't focus on the fact that it's `{}`.  This is just something that `_` uses as an "internal flag," per se, to indicate that a `.each` loop should be broken.

Comment: @pure_code technically yes, but the problem is that you could in theory compare to a string `'break'` in the loop, which would be a problem.  There can only ever be one instance of `breaker = {}`

Comment: @pure_code no it's not the same; if you knew what the hash digest was, you could *still* have it as an element of the array, which would cause unexpected loop breaking.  There can only be *one* `breaker`

Comment: @pure_code not that I know of without some kind of debugging tools

Answer (score 7):

Adding a `+` symbol effectively converts a variable into a number, such that:

```
+"1" === 1;
```

However, please note that

```
+"1" === "1"; // FALSE
+"1" ==  "1"; // TRUE
```

This is because `==` will convert its operands to the same type, whereas `===` will not.

That means that the test:

```
obj.length === +obj.length
```

Is essentially trying to test whether `obj.length` is numeric.

In Underscore, this code is trying to figure out if a variable of unknown type has a property called `length` and whether it is numeric. The assumption is that, if these are both true, you can iterate over the variable is if it were an array.

### EDIT

Please note, the OP's code has a number of bugs in it, not least of which is this approach to detecting if something is an Array (or Arraylike). The following object would cause problems:

```
var footballField = {
    covering: "astroturf",
    condition: "muddy",
    length: 100
};
```

I'm not advocating the above approach... just explaining someone else's.

Comment: Because an `Object` could have a `length` property that could be anything.

Comment: @pure_code: Use your imagination. `{length:"I'm clearly not a number"}`

Comment: Checking for a numeric `length` property is *not* good practice... the code snippet provided by the OP has a number of bugs in it, this being one of them.

Comment: @Dancrumb: It's neither a good nor bad practice. There needs to be *some* criteria used to determine if an object is "array-like" and therefore can be iterated. That's the criteria they've chosen. It's the user's fault if they didn't read the documentation, and therefore pass an object that they shouldn't.

Comment: Well, if the documentation for a library said: "Works for any object, so long as that object doesn't have a property called 'length', regardless of whether it makes sense", I'd consider it a pretty poor quality library.

Comment: It's worth noting that Underscore (which the OP's code is 'modified from') does *not* implement `isArray` in this way.

Answer (score 3):

The plus prefix converts the variable into a number. Basically, the `obj.length === +obj.length` is a sanity check that obj.length really is a number. If the `obj.length` was not a number, and for example a string `"foo"`, then `"foo" === +"foo"` would equate to false since `+"foo"` comes out as `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

The + prefix converts the value into a number.

Answer (score -1):

If the object does not have a `length` property (being a regular `Object`, instead of an `Array`), then calling `obj.length` will return `undefined`. A test for undefined would be clearer, but the implementor chose to first convert it to a number (so it will become `NaN`) and then compare it with the original value (using a strict comparison, which will ensure it will yield `false`).

**Update:** as others pointed out, this code seems to be concerned not only with `Array`s, but also "array-like" objects (i.e. objects that have a numeric `length` property and numeric indices). In such case, a test for `instanceof Array` would not be enough (and just testing for `undefined` might not be the best option, since there could be a `length` but of another type).

Comment: That's not what this comparison is for

Comment: @Dancrumb then what is it for? I see two code blocks, one to deal with arrays (using `for`) and another for objects (using "foreach"). Is my interpretation wrong?

Comment: A numeric conversion of `undefined` becomes `NaN`, not `0`.

Comment: For one thing, an Object could legitimately have a `length` property. Thus, checking for `undefined` would not be sufficient

Comment: @Dancrumb by making sure that the un-cast "length" property is equal to the "length" property converted to a number, the code is effectively the same as a test for a "length" property and a conjunctive test for that property to be numeric. Thus, it's a "duck typing" test to see if the object is an array.

Comment: @Dancrumb I agree, that's why I would test for `instanceof Array` myself (instead of using this confusing trick). But from the context, it's clear that the intention of the implementor was that (unless there's some more plausible explanation).

Comment: @Pointy except the presence of a property called `length` is a woefully insufficient test to see if an object is an array. The defining characteristics of an array include numeric indexes, not just a numeric `length`.

Comment: @Dancrumb well not if all the code wants to do is iterate through numeric-indexed properties. Lots of libraries do essentially that very thing. (Indeed, the code here is just a slightly broken version of code in the Underscore.js library.) Also, the numeric-indexed properties of an array object are *not really numeric-indexed* - **all** property names of **all** objects are treated as strings by the `[]` operator!  Really, it's just the "magic" `length` property that makes arrays special.

Comment: @Pointy That's one of the reasons that I use the Lodash implementation. Simply checking for `length` is shoddy work that opens users up to subtle bugs; especially since there is actually a *definitive* way to check.

Comment: @Dancrumb I think it boils down to a question of whether one believes in a "duck typing" world or not :-)  It could be considered a feature that non-array objects can actually pretend to be arrays with facilities like this.  I see both sides of the argument, and for me it's academic since I can't recall needing to do it in real life lately!

Comment: @Pointy: someone pointed to `HTMLCollection` and `NodeList` (in chat) as examples of non array objects that have numeric indexes. I guess the bottom line is that no implementation of `forEach` can be a perfect solution for all iterable entities in JS. I think I see both sides better now; I still prefer Lodash's rigour on this point, but I can see where it limits itself now.