# my javascript variables wont add correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

im having a problem adding these variables lets say 'pce'=100 and 'epbcac'=200 my result is 100200 instead of 300 what am i doing wrong thanks,

```
var pce = $('#pce').val();
var epbcac=$('#epbcac').val();

var results12 = pce + epbcac;

$('#tc').val(results12);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding strings.  You need to make them ints [`parseInt(string, radix)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp).

```
var results12 = parseInt(pce,10) + parseInt(epbcac,10);
```

As @Joe mentioned `radix` is optional, but if you dont specify it the browser could use a different radix and could cause unpredictable behavior.

---

Alternatively, as @DavidMcMullin suggested a Savvier way to do it is to use the [`unary +`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081880/what-is-unary-used-for-in-javascript) operator:

```
var results12  = +pce + + epbcac
```

---

[Radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) is the base of the number system.  Meaning the numbers that make up the system:

**Binary: radix=2**
01010101

**Decimal: radix=10**
0123456789

**Hex: radix=16**
0123456789ABCDEF

Comment: I would also specify the radix, parseInt(pce, 10); just in case.

Comment: Don't forget to specify the radix.

Comment: @user2120124 actually he was first.

Comment: Nix was first by a few seconds actually.

Comment: the unary + operator would be another option, if you feel like being more concise, although it also more cryptic... +pce + +epbcac

Comment: @DavidMcMullin I like it, i would post as an answer `+'200' + +'300'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt(pce);` and `parseInt(epbcac);` before summing it up.

Comment: Have proper radix while parsing int. for example parseInt(pce, 10);

Answer (score 0):

As others said, use `parseInt`, but ideally use

```
parseInt(pce,10) + parseInt(epbcac,10)
```

otherwise strings with leading zeros in the form "012" will be parsed incorrectly as hex digits and the addition won't work correctly.