# what it will print console.log(1+ + "2")

Tags: javascript

Why does this JavaScript statement:

```
console.log(1 +  + "2");
```

print

```
3
```

as the output? I am not sure why it's printing this - I expected "12".

Comment: Why don't you run the code yourself? Then you can still ask for an explanation. What in particular are you confused about?

Comment: @CoDeMurDeRer No, it's "valid" JavaScript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9081880/645956

Comment: `+` or `-` operand in front of a string converts it to number. so here `+"2"` will become `2` and then `1 + 2` which will be `3`.

Comment: they edit question... first was like `console.log(1 +  + ""2);` so i said that it will give error...

Comment: Hi @FelixKling, i can run the code, i know that. it is printing 3, i don't know how it is printing  3, that's why i asked. you are not talented guy when u was born.

Comment: *"it is printing 3, i don't know how it is printing 3, that's why i asked"* Then why didn't you just ask that instead of asking what the output is? As I said, asking for an explanation is perfectly fine. Asking for the result of one line of code is not. Also, I assume you must have put *some* thought into why the result is 3. What else would you have expected? If you explain your thoughts we can provide better answers.

Comment: @Siva you misunderstood felix. you didn't explain your question clearly so he asked like that. anyway don't mind the votes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`+` or `-` operand in front of a string converts it to number. so here `+"2"` will become `2` hence the result will be `3`.

```
=> 1 + + "2"    // +"2" = 2
=> 1 +    2
=> 3
```

If you use `-` in between like

```
=> 1 - - "2"   // -"2" = -2
=> 1 - - 2     // 1 - (-2)
=> 1 + 2
=> 3
```

So,

```
     -"2" ==> -2
     +"2" ==>  2
 +"Hello" ==> NaN
 -"Hello" ==> NaN
```

Comment: Could you explain why `1 + + "2"` transformed into `1 +    2` where as `1 - - "2"` into `1 - - 2`? I am bit confused about it.

Comment: @TamilVendhanKanagaraju I updated the post. I hope it is now clear.

Comment: Its clear now, but, I am still not able to understand that when `-"2"` is transformed into `-2`, why `+"2"` is not transformed into `+2`.

Comment: @TamilVendhanKanagaraju `+2` will be automatically become `2`. You will not write `+1 + 2` while calculating. you will just write `1 + 2`.

Comment: @Tam `-` in `-"2"` acts as a [unary negation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_negation_(-)) which negates the converted number 2 which is positive (+2). So, it goes like that: `-"2"` -> `-(+2)` -> `-2`.

Comment: @cychoi: [clap]. thanks everyone. i am clear now. thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(1 + "2")` prints 12 as `+` acts as an concatenation operator.

But if you try to print `console.log( + "2" )` you will get output as 2 coz it is casted as an integer.

Therefore `console.log( 1 + +"2" )` will give you result as 3

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the specific output of

```
console.log(1 +  + "2");
```

Run it on your browser console. The better question is why does it output what it does -

```
console.log(1 +  + "2");
              ^
```

That is the binary `+` operator, which will concatenate strings or add numbers.

```
console.log(1 +  + "2");
                 ^
```

That one is the unary `+` operator, which converts "2" to a number.

Don't create JavaScript like this. It's confusing.

Answer (score -3):

console.log(1 + "2");
This will give concated output 12

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34723595)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).