# How string works in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, math

I got a strange experience today while playing with js.

-> `'N'+ +'78'` this is equal to `"N78"`

-> `'78' + + 'g'` this is equal to `"78NaN"`

-> `'1' + + '5'`  this is equal to `'15'` but

-> `1 + + '5'`  is equal to `6`  and

->  `1 +  '5'`  is again  equal to `'15'`.

I understand the last point but not sure how JavaScript treats `+ +` operators in the string.

Comment: Very interesting.

Comment: Coercion is a funky thing. See [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/) for more info.

Comment: The `+` operator is working in three different ways here: Concatenation, addition, and negation (though because it's `+` and not `-`, you don't get a sign change). The rest is from type coercion since the things the operator works on need to be of the same type and javascript is helpful like that.

Comment: Hot take, I suppose: When I was in college, I believed that understanding these detailed rules of how a language is parsed represented knoweldge.  Then in the working world I found out that I have to use multiple languages that probably don't agree on these things - often several on the same project (especially where js is involved) - and this is just one of the reasons I came to relalize that unless you're writing a js parser, the only practical answer is "don't write code like that".

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22%2B+%2B%22+%5Bjs%5D) of [what it will print console.log(1+ + "2")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28493464/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some important rules:

1. The unary `+` operator coerces a value to a number.
2. `a + + b` is interpreted as `a + (+b)`.
3. `a + b` will either add numbers or concatenate strings.

   - if `a` and `b` are numbers, it will add them.
   - If either/both of `a` or `b` is not a number, it will coerce either/both to a string and then concatenate them.

Due to these rules, it's usually preferred to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for string concatenation. And for math use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to convert strings with numbers to actual numbers before using them with math operators. This will help keep you sane, because (as you've noticed) it gets a little weird when you write code like that.

---

So knowing the above rules, we can work through your examples:

```
 'N'+ +'78'
 'N' + (+'78') // how interpreter sees it
 'N' + 78      // unary + changes string '78' to number 78
 'N78'         // string + number coerces the number to a string.
```

---

```
'78' + + 'g'
'78' + (+'g') // how interpreter sees it
'78' + NaN    // unary + cannot convert 'g' to number, so NaN is returned instead.
'78NaN'       // NaN is coerced to a string and concatenated with the string '78'
```

---

```
'1' + + '5'
'1' + (+'5') // how interpreter sees it
'1' + 5      // unary + converts string '5' to number 5
'15'         // string + number coerces the number to a string and concatenates.
```

---

```
1 + + '5'
1 + (+'5') // how interpreter sees it
1 + 5      // unary + converts string '5' to number 5
6          // both operands are numbers, addition is performed.
```

---

```
1 + '5'
'15'       // number + string coerces the number to a string and concatenates.
```

---

You can even control this coercion by implementing a `toString` method on your own objects.

```js
const myObjA = {
  toString: () => 'A'
}

const myObjB = {
  toString: () => 'B'
}

console.log(123 + myObjA + myObjB) // '123AB'
```