# Is there any difference in using the " + " operator to push?

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

I was comparing two branches and there is a divergence in code while the `+ operator`, in my opinion **it doesn't make any difference** since it's push. 
Is there any difference?

Before

```
if (numberPattern.test(val)) {
            var getNumbers = val.match(numberPattern);
            for (i = 0; i < getNumbers.length; i++) {
                valores.push(getNumbers[i])
            }
        }
```

After

```
if (numberPattern.test(val)) {
            var getNumbers = val.match(numberPattern);
            for (i = 0; i < getNumbers.length; i++) {
                valores.push(+getNumbers[i])
            }
        }
```

Comment: If it's not causing an error i don't think it's a problem

Comment: The question is what is the use of this operator? I thought unnecessary

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is unary + used for in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081880/what-is-unary-used-for-in-javascript)

Comment: What i meant to say is that i don't see any difference. Instead if there had been two '+' could have been a problem..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is converting it to a `Number`, where the other case is leaving it as a string.

Comment: how do you know that `getNumber[i]` is returning a string?

Comment: Note that this technique differs from `parseFloat` in that it will convert booleans and empty strings as well ( + other edge cases )  I would not recommend it however because of readability.

Comment: @AmitJoki its because of the regex processing.

Answer (score 2):

`+` will actually change `getNumbers[i]` to a `number` type. The `+`(unary operator) is actually used to convert it to a `number`.

Try running this code:

```
var s = "1"; //String
var s1 = +s; //String changed to a number now
console.log(typeof s1);
```

You will see the type of `s1` will be `number`.