# jQuery - Simple divide two values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get different values from my input fields, divide them and show the result like this:

```
<input type="text" class="ad-title calculate form-control" name="budget" id="budget" value="" placeholder="Enter a daily budget in USD">

<input type="text" class="form-control calculate" id="ppc" name="ppc" value="" placeholder="">
```

My simple jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".calculate").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
         var budget = parseFloat($("#budget").val());
         var ppc = parseFloat($("#ppc").val());
         var value = ppc / budget;
        $("#sum").text(value);
    });
});
```

However, in my `#sum` div, all I see is: `NaN`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see it's money, are you putting in dollar signs in the input?

Comment: @9Deuce No, only numbers.

Comment: Does the decimal point of the currency value match your langauge settings  ?

Comment: @cloudworks that doesn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: hey do you really need keyup? it's acting funny with keyevents!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could so this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".calculate").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
        var budget = parseFloat($("#budget").val()) || 0;
        var ppc = parseFloat($("#ppc").val()) || 0;

        var value = ppc / budget;

        if (!isNaN(value) && value !== Infinity) {
            $("#sum").text(value);
        }
    });
});
```

You may have to alter it to match your needs. For example, we'll get `NaN` or Not a Number when dividing by zero so handle that. Maybe you never want to show 0 so maybe handle that or make the default for budget `1`. It depends on how you want it to work.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f0t45c7x/1

Comment: this also gives me infinity. Seems like when I am editing my first .calculate field (the #budget one), it doesn't take/read that value. Why, I have no idea. I thought the .bind() function would take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your values to numbers using the [`+` unary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081880/what-is-unary-used-for-in-javascript) instead of using `parseFloat` :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".calculate").bind("keyup change", function (e) {
        var budget = +$("#budget").val();
        var ppc = +$("#ppc").val();
        if(!budget || !ppc) return false; // Wait till both values are set
        var value = ppc / budget;
        $("#sum").text(value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="ad-title calculate form-control" name="budget" id="budget" value="" placeholder="Enter a daily budget in USD">
<input type="text" class="form-control calculate" id="ppc" name="ppc" value="" placeholder="">
<div id="sum"></div>
```

Comment: This gives me the result "infinity" (no matter what values I try)

Comment: The snippet above works for me in Chrome. What browser are you using, @oliverbj ?

Comment: I suppose when I get infinity, it's because a division by zero is occuring. Although I am entering other values than zero

Comment: Now it doesn't show anything in the #sum. I can see that my original code doesn't update before the 2nd .calculate input is filled out (got me thinking that maybe it doesn't regonize any change to the first .calculate input

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
var ppc = parseFloat($("#ppc").val());
```

to

```
var ppc = parseFloat($("#ppc").val()) || 0;
```

Comment: You need to check if the value is undefined or nothing. By putting || this means "if empty then set to 0"

Comment: Actually, it's a logical or which means if the value on the left is logically false, it'll go with the value on the right. It may or may not have the behavior desired but it'll handle empty string, undefined and NaN.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to bind "change" event, this should do,

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".calculate").bind("keyup", function(e) {
        var budget = parseFloat($("#budget").val()) || 0;
        var ppc = parseFloat($("#ppc").val()) || 0;

        var value = (ppc / budget);
       // alert(value);
        if (!isNaN(value) && value != Infinity) {
            $("#sum").text(value);
        }
        else{
            $("#sum").text("0")
        }
    });
});
```