# NodeJs readfilesync returns NAN not file contents

Tags: node.js

I have written a code for reading a file contents while i running it does not returns file contents but NAN. Below is my code:-

```
var fs = require('fs');

if (fs.existsSync('Temp')){
console.log('Directory exists, removing...');
if(fs.existsSync('Temp/new.txt')){
    fs.unlinkSync('Temp/new.txt');
}
fs.rmdirSync('Temp');
}

fs.mkdirSync('Temp');

console.log('running');

if(fs.existsSync('Temp')){
process.chdir('Temp');
fs.writeFileSync('test.txt', 'This is some test text for the file2');
fs.renameSync('test.txt', 'new.txt');
console.log('File has size:', + fs.statSync('new.txt').size + ' bytes');
console.log('File contents:', + fs.readFileSync('new.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'}));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [unary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081880/what-is-unary-used-for-in-javascript) which converts anything to number instead of concatenating the output.

You either, remove the comma (`,`) from your `console.log` and use string concatenation, or remove the `+` and send the content as `console.log` second argument.

```
// I'm concatenating here
console.log('File contents:' + fs.readFileSync('new.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'}));
// I'm sending the content as second argument of console.log
console.log('File contents:', fs.readFileSync('new.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'}));
```

What you are doing, can be translated to this, which will return `NaN` unless `new.txt` content is a number.

```
console.log(
    'File contents:', 
    Number(fs.readFileSync('new.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'}))
);
```

```js
console.log('File content: ', + 'new.txt content'); // NaN
console.log('File content: ', Number('new.txt content')); // NaN

console.log('File content: ', 'new.txt content'); // ok
console.log('File content: ' + 'new.txt content'); // ok
```

Comment: Thanks Marcos, this was helpful.

I accidently committed the same mistake of using ',' and '+' together which was causing it to return Nan.